# Is it possible to setup a new WooCommerce payment method with an API key without using a plugin in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, payment-gateway, payment, api-key, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am new to WordPress and I wanted to create a payment method in WordPress website. The payment method I want to use is only found in my country and it's new. It doesn't have a WordPress plugin yet in WooCommerce.

I only have the API key of the payment gateway so is there a way to use the API key on the website so that it can create a connection with the payment gateway? Or am I understanding the whole concept wrong anyway?

Any help would be appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, yes, if you add the required code to integrate the new payment method into your shop. That's what plugins do.

Comment: so it means i have to create a plugin for it right? @cabrerahector

Comment: Yes, or just add your custom code to your theme's functions.php file as bhanu below suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add payment gateway support without creating an API. You can add your custom code in `functions.php` file of your child theme. [Why child theme?](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/set-up-and-use-a-child-theme/)

The way you integrate payment gateway with woocommerce is explained in this article by WooCommerce team itself.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/payment-gateway-api/

I would suggest you to go through it.

Instead of

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'init_your_gateway_class' );
```

You can use

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'init_your_gateway_class' );
```

other codes goes as is.

Comment: thank you for your response. just to be sure the one you suggested is the only way to add this new payment method in my WordPress right? I mean is there a way with out the involvement of woocommerece  it just that someone i know says there might be a way without woocommerece so i just wanted to what is your comment on that?  @bhanu

Comment: Well yes, you don't need to have WooCoomerce to get payment completed. For that you will first have to look if their is any other plugin which would accept payment for the payment gateway, if there isn't sucha a solution then you will need to make a completely custom solution with interface for the inputs which would then connect to the gateway using the proper API provided by the gateway. That's all I can say with the information provided.

Comment: But If you are selling somethign I would suggest you to use woocommerce, it is highly capable of fitting to every use case. @user14078202